# EE v2.9.0 Relationship Need to display like entries

Tags: ee2, relationships

I have a couple of channels...

SUCCESS STORY
SERVICES

...and I am displaying single entries in the SUCCESS STORIES by {url_title}. At the bottom of the entry being viewed, I would like to display related SUCCESS STORY entries. In other words, SUCCESS STORY entries that share common SERVICES. I have a relationship field (multiple) named SERVICES USED that points to SERVICES. I am in the single entry with the following tag pair:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel='success_story' 
    limit='1' 
    url_title='{segment_3}' 
    disable='categories|member_data|pagination' 
}
    ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Inside the tag pair, I am displaying information regarding the services used like so:

```
{services_used}
    {services_used:service_copy}
        <div class="expand">{if "{services_used:service_copy:headline}" != ""}{services_used:service_copy:headline}{if:else}{services_used:title}{/if}</div>
        <div class="collapse">
            {exp:eehive_hacksaw 
                words='25' 
                allow='<p>' 
                append='...'
            }
                {services_used:service_copy:copy}
            {/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
            <p class="text-right">
                <a href="{services_used:title_permalink='services/details'}" target="_self" class="button highlight small">Tell me more</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    {/services_used:service_copy}
{/services_used}
```

Inside that tag pair is where I would like to display other SUCCESS STORY entries sharing the same SERVICES listed from the SERVICES USED loop there.

*** EDIT ***

I have also tried the Accessing Siblings like in the docs here: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/relationships.html#accessing-siblings

Using the relationship field loop since I am already in the "parent channel". Something like this:

```
{relationship_field}
    {relationship_field:siblings field="relationship_field"}
        {relationship_field:siblings:title}
    {/relationship_field:siblings}
{/relationship_field}
```

Which translated to something like this:

```
<h3>RELATED SUCCESS STORIES</h3>
{services_used}
    {services_used:siblings field="services_used"}
        {services_used:siblings:title}
    {/services_used:siblings}
{/services_used}
```

But since I already looped through the relationship field above this, I just get the tag output like an error on the screen:

RELATED SUCCESS STORIES
{services_used:siblings field="services_used"} {services_used:siblings:title}

{/services_used:siblings} {services_used:siblings field="services_used"} {services_used:siblings:title}

{/services_used:siblings} {services_used:siblings field="services_used"} {services_used:siblings:title}

{/services_used:siblings}

Comment: Why services can't be categories?

Comment: Because there is a services section in which they have service names and descriptions. Pages dedicated to the services themselves. The success stories are about different clients using those services. It made more sense to simply relate them to keep them pertinent.